# setTimeout and difference in Time

Tags: javascript

I have a loop kind of like this

```
var lastUpdateTime = (new Date()).getTime(),
    diffTime = 0,
    i = 0;

function update() {
    var updateTime = 1000 / 60,
        now;

    // do some stuff...

    console.log("update");
    console.log(" - i:" + i);

    now = (new Date()).getTime();
    diffTime = now - lastUpdateTime;
    lastUpdateTime = now;

    console.log(" - - before diffTime:" + diffTIme);

    while (diffTime >= updateTime) {
        diffTime -= updateTime;
    }

    console.log(" - - after diffTime:" + diffTime);

    updateTime -= diffTime;

    console.log(" - - updateTime:" + updateTime);

    if ( i < 10) {
        i += 1;
        setTimeout(update, updateTime);
    }
}
```

When setTimeout is called, the time that has passed during the updateTime does not seem to of passed when diffTime is updated. Here, I have set it to be `1000 / 60` milliseconds, but I get numbers there are less than that, which doesn't make sense. It should be more than or equal to. Why is it doing that?

**In response to davin:**
I don't use `setInterval` because it stacks the calls http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts.

The `while` reduces the diffTime into `1000 / 60` blocks of time, especially when it is greater than 16 ms. Modulus operator is expensive.

The reason I know that the `updateTime` hasn't passed is that print out the `diffTime` before I manipulate it. The number always comes out less than `updateTime` given to `setTimeout`.

**Log:**

```
update
- i:0
- - before diffTime:1
- - after diffTime:1
- - updateTime:15.666666666666668
update
- i:1
- - before diffTime:12
- - after diffTime:12
- - updateTime:4.666666666666668
update
- i:2
- - before diffTime:54
- - after diffTime:3.999999999999993
- - updateTime:12.666666666666675
update
- i:3
- - before diffTime:13
- - after diffTime:13
- - updateTime:3.666666666666668
update
- i:4
- - before diffTime:11
- - after diffTime:11
- - updateTime:5.666666666666668
update
- i:5
- - before diffTime:14
- - after diffTime:14
- - updateTime:2.666666666666668
```

Looking at the `updateTime` and the `before diffTime`, the timing doesn't make sense. For example I have `15.666666666666668`, but the difference in time after it is `12`.

**New Log:**

```
updateWithoutTimer
- i:0
- - before diffTime:2
- - after diffTime:2
- - updateTime:14.666666666666668
updateWithoutTimer
- i:1
- - before diffTime:5
- - after diffTime:5
- - updateTime:11.666666666666668
updateWithoutTimer
- i:2
- - before diffTime:8
- - after diffTime:8
- - updateTime:8.666666666666668
updateWithoutTimer
- i:3
- - before diffTime:86
- - after diffTime:2.66666666666665
- - updateTime:14.000000000000018
updateWithoutTimer
- i:4
- - before diffTime:24
- - after diffTime:7.333333333333332
- - updateTime:9.333333333333336
updateWithoutTimer
- i:5
- - before diffTime:34
- - after diffTime:0.6666666666666643
- - updateTime:16.000000000000004
updateWithoutTimer
- i:6
- - before diffTime:24
- - after diffTime:7.333333333333332
- - updateTime:9.333333333333336
updateWithoutTimer
- i:7
- - before diffTime:27
- - after diffTime:10.333333333333332
- - updateTime:6.333333333333336
updateWithoutTimer
- i:8
- - before diffTime:14
- - after diffTime:14
- - updateTime:2.666666666666668
updateWithoutTimer
- i:9
- - before diffTime:2
- - after diffTime:2
- - updateTime:14.666666666666668
updateWithoutTimer
- i:10
- - before diffTime:2
- - after diffTime:2
- - updateTime:14.666666666666668
```

Here is another log that does not do it only on the first tick. When I have tested it, it seems to work like `setTimeout(func)`, so no millisecond elapse. The delay seems to be the browser. Currently I am using Mozilla Aurora 6.0a and Google Chrome 14.0.803 dev.
I thought I would just recheck both browsers and I go the same result in Aurora, but Chrome worked as expected. Oddly I tested it before hand and it didn't work correctly. I assume it is a bug in Aurora. I have submitted a bug report to mozilla.

I assign lastTimeUpdate because I want to find out how long it has taken to get to this frame and how long the frame has taken, so I can process it accordingly.

**Update:**
Here is the bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=668765. Apparently, `setTimeout` will try to do the right thing. If it has recently fired late it will try to fire early.

Comment: You're wrong about the mod operator (in terms of both execution time and readability). More importantly, did you read the second paragraph that I wrote? I don't think you understand the maths that is executed in your code: you're setting the interval for a small amount of time and wondering why it's small. I think you're comparing `diffTime` to `16` and wondering why it's smaller. You should compare it to the value of `updateTime` **after** you have changed it. I ran this several times and they always came out as expected.

Comment: I do understand what your saying, but taking in what you said, if I change `updateTime` for `1000 / 60`, then there should be a gap more or equal to `1000 / 60` ms, but I get 2, 3, and 4 ms. If you tested it and it works as expected, it must be my actual code.
the mod operator, divides, floors and then take away to work out the reminder. I'm just doing a simple loop.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. I suggest you test it on a few other browsers though. Like I said it works fine for me on Chrome 12. I wasn't wondering why you have `lastTimeUpdate` I was saying that you set it's value in the wrong place (i.e. you would get a better approximation by setting it's value later).

Comment: What i meant was I do it where I do it, because I need to do all the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense to me. What is that `while` loop doing? Why not just have a modulus operator after rounding and do it in 1 step? Why are you subtracting this difference in such a strange manner? On what basis do you claim that the time hasn't passed? I see no checking of any value.

Of course you're getting values that are `<= updateTime = 1000/60 ~ 16`, because *you* set the interval to be such: You loop until `diffTime < updateTime` and then execute the new timer for a delay of `updateTime - diffTime`. The maths is simple: `0 < updateTime - diffTime < updateTime`.

It looks like you want to update every so often. That's why they invented `setInterval`. You're reinventing the wheel which is both unnecessary and less reliable than the browser's implementation.

**UPDATE**

I presume you're not an assembly programmer. The modulus operator will perform a constant number of arithmetic operations, say 4 worst-case. Your loop will perform almost the same number of operations **each iteration**, since it has to perform the condition check, the subtraction, the assignment and a branch (which can itself be expensive). So if your loop does even 2 iterations its already more expensive than a modulus operator.

Regarding your times, you say that it happens "all the time" although from that output it looks like it happens only the first time. I ran the same code and the numbers made sense. What platform are you running on? Does this ever happen other than on the first tick? Does it happen *every time* on the first tick? Some more information would be helpful.

As an aside, you're overestimating your `diffTime` because you're setting `lastUpdateTime` before you do a whole bunch of things. What you should be doing is assigning `lastUpdateTime` at the point of `setTimeout`.

Comment: @kuroutadori, as have I to the answer.

Comment: Okay, your got me on the mod.